# Computing rectangle around pixel coordinates

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, blobs

I have a Qvector containing pixel coordinates of an image. The main goal would be to group those pixels regarding their distance to each other and getting a rectangle out of those groups of pixels. Every pixel in the vector are not close to each other and that is the reason why I would like to group them.

I am using openCv and Qt. I would like to avoid the blobDetector from OpenCV which is quite slow and do this by my own if that is possible.

Does anybody have an idea how to manage this ?

**EDIT:**

Let's say the white dots are pixel close to each other. The main objective would be to detect that these pixels are close to each other and be able to get a rectangle of those pixels. Is this possible ?

[image]

**EDIT2:**

After getting the clusters I tried to get the bounding rectangles around those clusters with the following code. I might not be using this function the correct way.

```
cv::partition(cvCoordsTable, testVector, Dist(eqludianThreshold));
std::vector<cv::Rect> rectTable;

for(int in = 0; in < testVector.size(); in++)
{
    rectTable.push_back(cv::boundingRect(cvCoordsTable.at(in)));
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: what is the expected number of groups? seems like a clustering problem to me, could you please show some input and the output you desire?

Comment: I don't really know the expected number of groups. Let's say that those pixel coordinates are the pixels that changed between two frames of a video. Depending on these frames it can be very different that is why I can't really give you an expected number. I added information on my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clustering problem in the first place. Since you do not know the number of clusters (groups) you have to use some algorithm that does not need the number of clusters as input. You can do simple [cv::partition](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/clustering.html#partition)  which has the following signature in C++:

```
int cv::partition(const vector<_Tp>& vec, vector<int>& labels, _EqPredicate predicate=_EqPredicate())
```

**Example of using it:**

```
    std::vector<cv::Point> pixelCoordinatesTable,
    std::vector<int> labelsTable;
    double threshold= 5;//Max eqludian distance between one cluster points
    cv::partition(pixelCoordinatesTable, labelsTable, [&threshold](auto const& l, auto const& r){
        return cv::norm(l - r))<threshold;
    });
```

Another and more mature option will be using a real clustering algorithm like [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN). Which is a density based clustering algorithm. and you can find a C++ [implementation here](https://github.com/propanoid/DBSCAN).

After you got the clusters (in any method) just apply `cv::boundingRect` around each `cluster` to get the `rectangle` you want.

**EDIT:**

To solve the rectangle problem:

```
auto cluster_count = cv::partition(cvCoordsTable, testVector, Dist(eqludianThreshold)); // gettting the number of clusters
std::vector<cv::Rect> rectTable;
rectTable.reserve(cluster_count);//Optimiaztion
for(int in = 0; in < cluster_count; in++){
    std::vector<cv::Point> temp;
    temp.reserve(testVector.size());
    for(size_t i=0;i<testVector.size();++i){
        if(testVector[i]==in){
             temp.emplace_back(rectTable[i]);
        }
    }
    rectTable.emplace_back(cv::boundingRect(temp));
}
```

I am sure there is a better and faster way, I was just explaining the idea and you may optimise it as you can.

Comment: That seems nice. Let's say I have a std::vector<cv::Point> pixelCoordinatesTable, will it be correct to use cv::partition(pixelCoordinatesTable, labelsTable); or is there another way to use it ?

Comment: Now that I have the labelsTable filled out, how should I call the boudingRect function ? Do i have to loop between each labelsTable element and create a rectangle according to the pixelCoordinates table ? Thank you very much for your precise answer !

Comment: I've just tried to loop with boudingRects but I'm having incorrect results. Could you give me a tip on how I can use it ? Thank you

Comment: see my edited post please. Plus, do I have to sort the values inside de labelsTable ? since it is not consecutive numbers all the time. E.g. 0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,0,3,3,3,3 etc...

Comment: @RobertJones I wrote you a small /untested/ example

Answer (score 2):

@Humam Helfawi beat me here, but anyway, if you got a list of center points, use cv::partition to do (unsupervised) clustering:

```
struct Dist
{
    double D;
    Dist(double d) : D(d) {}
    bool operator()(const Point &a, const Point &b)
    {
        return (a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x) + (a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y) < D;
    }
};
vector<Point> centers; // e.g. from findContours -> boundingRect
vector<int> labels;
cv::partition(centers,labels,Dist(800));
cerr << Mat(labels).t() << endl;
```

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

Comment: That's also perfect just as @Human Helfawi. One question though, what is the average eqludian distance I should use ? You use a threshold of 800 whereas Humam uses 5.

Comment: I did not :D I just put random number.

Comment: 800 is more the *square* of the distance (to save a sqrt call)

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Oh all right I just had a doubt about this !

Comment: @berak nice Idea since we do not need to know the real distance .. sqrt is really expensive.